# Cookie Layer GPDR configuration

Tags: jquery, ajax, cookies, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I use Tag Manager for tracking the trraffic on my site, when a user goes into my web, the new normative GPDR don't let it track the visit if the user does not accept new policices or navigate by site (naviagation equal accept polices).

My question is:

If the user accepts the polices whithin the cookies layer, How I can track the visit in this moment without having to reload the page?

Comment: Set your tracker to fire on event(accept the polices) instead of pageview.

Answer (score 0):

As Matus pointed out in his comment you can send a (virtual) pageview to Google Analytics that is triggered by a GTM event. Due to the way GA creates sessions it is quite important that the first hit in the session is indeed a pageview, and not an event.

So when the user accepts you push an "event" key to the datalayer, and use that in a trigger that fires a Google Analytics tags that is configured to send a pageview (i.e. "pageview" is selected in Track Type dropdown).

The slightly confusing bit here is that you do not need an actual pageview in the browser to send a pageview to GA, but that's just because the same word is reused for several related, but independent things.